# Click on element in Webbrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, button, click

I have about 10 of these tags under each other:

```
<a class="answer" href="#">This is one</a>
<a class="answer" href="#">This is Two</a>
<a class="answer" href="#">This is Three</a>
```

Now I need my webbrowser in C# to click on `<a class="answer" href="#">This is Two</a>`

How would I do this? Only got text and a  tag with a class. No value this time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want it just for that "This is Two" link I believe it would go something like this:

```
HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");

foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.InnerText.Equals("This is Two"))
        link.InvokeMember("Click");
}
```